"Unable to Create App State Field 'saveforlater' with Document Reference Data Type in Flutter Flow"
Story
In my Flutter Flow project, I'm working on implementing an app with functionality similar to a shopping cart. I have successfully implemented the "Add to Cart" feature, but I am encountering an issue with the "Save for Later" feature.
The "Add to Cart" feature was set up as follows:

I added an app state field named cart.
I selected the data type as "Document Reference" and referenced courses.
I wrapped the cart item card in a List View to generate dynamic children.
I added a variable named cartItems and set its value to cart.
I clicked on the cart item again, added a backend query, selected the data type as    "Document Reference," selected the reference as courses, and set the value to cartItems.
This allowed me to bind the data inside the card and maintain the app state so that when the "Add to Cart" button is clicked, the cart item gets added to the cart.


I am trying to replicate this logic for the "Save for Later" feature, but I encounter the following issue:

I go to "Add App State."
I enter the field name saveforlater (I have also tried other names like savedItems and wishlist).
I select the data type as "Document Reference."
At this point, the "Create" button becomes unclickable.

Despite the "courses" reference being properly set up and accessible, and the fact that no validation messages or errors appear when the button becomes disabled, I am unable to proceed with creating the saveforlater field. I have double-checked the configuration for the cart field, and it works correctly, indicating that the setup steps I followed are sound.
I have also tried:
•   Using different field names, which did not resolve the issue.
•   Checking for validation messages or errors, but none appear.
•   Ensuring the "courses" reference is correctly set up and accessible.
To summarize, I am unable to create the saveforlater app state field with the "Document Reference" data type because the "Create" button becomes unclickable, even though the same steps work for the cart field. Additionally, the backend query setup, which works fine for cart, does not seem to influence this issue. I need to understand why this discrepancy occurs and how to resolve it so that I can implement the "Save for Later" feature successfully.
